# LeanTween not doing anything because of timescale 0. What's the work around?

Tags: unity-game-engine, leantween

Here's the problem. I set up a scoreboard, and made it so that my leantween would ease in some images (number of stars) on the scoreboard.

**Here's the code that calls the void:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class ScoreBoard : MonoBehaviour
{

public float timerassesshigh; //change for every level (for gold)
public float timerassesslow; //change for every level (for silver)
public timer timer;
private SceneFadeEffect sceneFade;
private Scene scene;
public int nextLevelRecord;
private int levelcurrentat;
public string NextLevel;
public AudioSource leveldonedun;
private GameObject musicg;
public AudioSource music;
public Animator leveldonefade;
public Image leveldonefadesprite;
public GameObject buttons;
public rankaudioandlog rankaudioandlog;

private void Awake()
{
}


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    levelcurrentat = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelreached");
    sceneFade = FindObjectOfType<SceneFadeEffect>();
    timer = FindObjectOfType<timer>();
    leveldonefade.enabled = false;
    leveldonefadesprite.enabled = false;
    buttons.SetActive(false);
}

public void leveldone()
{
    buttons.SetActive(true);
    leveldonefadesprite.enabled = true;
    leveldonefade.Rebind();
    leveldonedun.Play();
    music.Stop();
    if (timerassesshigh >= timer.time)
    {
        rankaudioandlog.gotgold();
    }
}
```

**And here's the code that contains the leantween**

```
public class rankaudioandlog : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public AudioSource bronze;
        public AudioSource silver;
        public AudioSource gold;
        public GameObject goldobject;
        public GameObject silverobject;
        public GameObject bronzeobject;
        public AudioSource leveldonecue;
        private int levelnumberrank;
        public string levelnumber;
        public LeanTweenType InType;


        private void Start()
        {
            levelnumberrank = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(("rankoflevel") + (levelnumber));
        }

        public void gotgold()
        {
            Debug.Log("You got gold!" + "on level" + levelnumber);
            LeanTween.scale(bronzeobject, new Vector3(6.5f, 6.5f, 0f), 0.2f).setDelay(1.2f).setEase(InType);
            bronze.PlayDelayed(2f);
            LeanTween.scale(silverobject, new Vector3(6.5f, 6.5f, 0f), 0.2f).setDelay(2.2f).setEase(InType);
            silver.PlayDelayed(3f);
            LeanTween.scale(goldobject, new Vector3(6.5f, 6.5f, 0f), 0.2f).setDelay(3.2f).setEase(InType);
            gold.PlayDelayed(4f);
            cueendsong();
            if (levelnumberrank == 3)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("I logged gold");
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt(("rankoflevel") + (levelnumber), 3);
            }
        }
        }
```

**Now, on another function, when the level ends and scoreboard is called, timescale becomes 0. That's why the leantween doesn't work. I need a workaround for that. Timescale has to stay 0, and leantween should start**

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**OK, I figured it out!**

I just had to add .setIgnoreTimeScale(true); to the tween.

Sorry for the trouble, and hopefully I helped someone too ^^.